# Zend_Date strange probleb

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I use

```
<?php 
    $date = '2014-09-01 14:01:52';
    $dateObject = new Zend_Date($date);
    $tranDate = $dateObject->get(Zend_Date::ATOM);
    echo $tranDate;
?>
```

2014-**09-01**T14:01:52+00:00

it's correct, but i noticed than several times it returned
2014-**01-09**T14:01:52+00:00

Does anybody know what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to your $locale.

You should be fine doing this

```
$dateObject = new Zend_Date($date, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
```

Or, if you want to be "cleaner", instead of writing the string, check out Zend constants for dates here
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.date.constants.html